# SystemJS.registerDynamic() equivalent function in the latest version of SystemJS

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

We have this old code which was written in SystemJS version **0.21.3**. We are trying to use the latest version of SystemJS to load the module dynamically from an in-memory JavaScript variable.

Can anyone point me to latest alternative to `registerDynamic` and then `import` the same.

Basically we need write this code in latest version of SystemJS. If this can be done using any other framework then that is also fine.

```js
import * as _dal from 'data-access-layer';
import * as _ngbForms from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as _ngCommon from '@angular/common';
import * as _ngCore from '@angular/core';
import * as _ngForms from '@angular/forms';
import * as _ngHttpClient from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-mod',
  templateUrl: './custom-mod.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-mod.component.css']
})
export class CustomModComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.LoadComponent()
  }

  LoadComponent() {
    SystemJS.set('@angular/core', SystemJS.newModule(_ngCore));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/common', SystemJS.newModule(_ngCommon));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/forms', SystemJS.newModule(_ngForms));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/common/http', SystemJS.newModule(_ngHttpClient));
    SystemJS.set('@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap', SystemJS.newModule(_ngbForms))

    const normalized = SystemJS.normalizeSync("@customModule-" + this.id);

    if (SystemJS.has(normalized)) {
      SystemJS.delete(normalized);
    }

    SystemJS.registerDynamic("@customModule-" + this.id, ['@angular/core', '@angular/common', '@angular/forms', '@angular/common/http', '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap', '@dal', '@app'], false, (require, exports, module) => {
      return new Function('require', 'exports', 'module', this.Javascript)(require, exports, module);
    });

    SystemJS.import("@customModule-" + this.id).then((module) => {
      this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module.default)
        .then((compiled) => {
          let moduleRef = compiled.ngModuleFactory.create(this.injector);

          const _injector = moduleRef.injector;
          const widgets = _injector.get('widgets');
          const resolver = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver;
          const componentFactory = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(widgets[0][0].component);

          this.conponentRef = this.vc.createComponent(componentFactory);
          this.conponentRef.instance.OnLoad();
        });
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your enviroment configuration, please? Are you using angular cli?

Comment: if don't, please have a look in this article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab

Comment: Can you please add code of `this.Javascript`?

Comment: Yes, this is Angular. But this code will run in browser, basically we are trying to provide plugins for our app, where in users can write HTML, TS and CSS in our webApp and it gets loaded

Comment: Can you recreate simple example in old systemjs version somewhere, e.g in stackblitz or in github repository?